# SWT - Accelerator not shown in Context (SWT.POP_UP) Menu

Tags: java, menu, swt

When setting accelerators for `MenuItem`s in a `Menu` with SWT.BAR as the style, the accelerators appear and work as a keyboard shortcut.

When the parent (root) menu is a SWT.POP_UP however, the accelerators don't appear and they don't work as a keyboard shortcut. When calling `.getAccelerator()` on a MenuItem that has an accelerator, the result is non-zero.

Example Code:

```
Menu menu = new Menu(tree, SWT.POP_UP);
MenuItem testItem = new MenuItem(menu);
testItem.setText("Test Item");
testItem.setAccelerator(SWT.MOD1 | 'T'); //Ctrl/Cmd + T
```

The following produes the string '262228' in console (on platforms that use SWT.CONTROL for MOD1)

```
System.out.println(testItem.getAccelerator());
```

SWT Version: 4.4
Testing environment: Linux/Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: It might help if you show us the code you are using for the context menu.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @Baz Question edited